# div doesn't fully expand to content

Tags: html, css, height

I'm not a css expert but I'm running out of ideas what could trigger this unwanted behaviour. I'm want to use a `div` as background for the main section of my site. Once there is a lot of content in my `div content` the `div content_wrapper` doesn't fully expand. This a section of my HTML

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Some heading</h1>
        <p>lot's of text</p>
    </div>
<footer>
    <div id="foot">
        <a id="disclaimer" href="disclaimer.html"> disclaimer</a> 
    </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

And the .css.

```
.content_wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 215px;
    background-color: #EEE;

}
.content{
    z-index: 5;
    float:left;
    margin: 50px 0 50px 20px;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-left: dashed 1px #CCC;
    border-top: dashed 1px #CCC;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

Any ideas what is going on and why?

Comment: verify that your body AND html are both 100% width and height

Comment: i don't see a problem http://jsfiddle.net/kLkwF/

Comment: Your `.content-wrapper` has a fixed height of 100%(of it's parent, in your case I guess body). That means the height of your wrapper is independent from the height of your `.content`.

Comment: @Morpheus, The background is only half grey. So the problem is still there...

Comment: @SvenBieder, True but when I don't specify the height if will not fully expand if there is less content, e.g. leave a white space.

Answer (score 1):

Change your .content_wrapper to this code:

```
.content_wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 215px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

You shouldn't be using position:absolute to allow it to expand to its parent. And, as of leaving the use of position:absolute, you should use margin-top then, instead of top.

Comment: I need the `position absolute` because of an `div` overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the content-wrapper to position:relative instead of absolute. 
And get rid of the float on your .content .

Either that, or put a clearing div beneath it.

```
.content_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 215px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.content {
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 50px 0 50px 20px;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-left: dashed 1px #CCC;
    border-top: dashed 1px #CCC;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the combination of `position: absolute`and `width/height: 100%`.

The 100% refer to the element's parent, which is `body`. So `content_wrapper` would be as large as the body. But it is also positioned absolutely and therefore taken out of the flow. Which means that the size of `body`does not change with the size of the content. Which in turn means that `content_wrapper` does not grow either and the content is only visible because of the overflow.

Don't use width and height and you should be fine.

Comment: Makes sense but if I don't use `height: 100%;` the div won't expand as needed either.

Comment: For a lot of text, yes. For less content it leaves me with a background not fully filled.

Comment: I see. You can use `min-height: 100%` for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

> .content_wrapper{
>       width: 100%;
>       height: 100%;
>       margin-top: 215px;
>       background-color: #EEE;
>       z-index:-999;
>       position:absolute;
>   }

the z-index should layer it at the bottom.
please tell me if that is not what you're looking for or it does not work